# Instalar o SQL Server com a aplicação

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, sql-server, deploy

Estou finalizando uma aplicação e irei compilar usando o Inno Setup. O sistema estou usando o SQL Server.

Irei instalar o sistema em outros computadores.

A base de dados é instalada nos computadores que receberão a aplicação ou terei que instalar o SQLerver em cada computador?

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Depende do que você fez, mas eu diria que não é necessário instalar em todos computadores, em geral ele só é necessário no computador que será o servidor.

É claro que se você fez tudo sem pensar nisto antes pode ter problemas para acessar o servidor e terá que arrumar a configuração da aplicação. Uma coisa é fazer para rodar na sua máquina, outra é fazer para rodar remotamente. Obviamente no servidor terá que instalar o SQL Server, e se já tem uma base de dados básica para começar rodar a aplicação, ele deve ser colocada lá.

Se usou algum biblioteca extra para a cessar o SQL Server que não as padrões do .NET, terá que distribuí-la na sua instalação.

Há casos que a aplicação pode precisar do banco de dados no cliente também. Aí não é recomendado o uso do SQL Server. Pelo menos não na sua versão completa. É melhor o uso do [SQL Server Compact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-compact-40) que é um banco de dado embutido na aplicação. Ou melhor ainda, usar o [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), até porque o SQL Compact foi descontinuado.

Comment: Entendi... mas se for instalar localmente? Pois vejo alguns programas que baixamos da internet e que são instalados localmente. Isso seria possível?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que quer dizer mas sim, é possível, dá até para incluir o SQL Server na instalação. O que não quer dizer que ele possa ser instalado sem pagar nada. Fora do desenvolvimento ele precisa ser licenciado e custa caro. Eu acho que a não ser que tenho um bom motivo o banco instalado localmente ou é *demo* ou tem alguma coisa característica muito específica. Claro que se precisa de uma pequena base de dados local muito simples o mais comum é usar o SQLite. Antes se recomendava o uso do SQL Server Compact mas nem a Microsoft incentiva mais com a veemência de antes e fala em SQLite

Comment: Acho que o no seu caso deveria usar o SQLlite mesmo como o @bigown disse. Instalar várias instâncias do SQL Server seria trabalhoso e bem caro. Qual tamanho da sua aplicação? Se for grande e o acesso ao banco de dados for intenso, ai já é melhor pensar em ter um servidor para centralizar o banco de dados.

Comment: Certo. A aplicação é pequena. Uma agenda para a sala de reuniões que ficará com a recepcionista. Conterá apenas o nome do solicitante, a data e as horas de entrada e entrega.... Nesse caso, como eu faria para aplicar o SQLite na minha aplicação? Ele está atualmente no SqlServer ( que veio com o Visual Studio Express 2013 )

Comment: De fato parece ser algo simples demais e que faz sentido ficar só localmente, mas aí já é outra pergunta. Veja o [tour] e a [help]. Para resumir: a não ser que tenha feito pensando na troca, o que não parece ser o caso, tem que reescrever todo mecanismo de acesso a dados da aplicação.