# Instalar banco de dados junto com a aplicação C#

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, instalador

Estou finalizando uma agenda da sala de reuniões que ficará na recepção da empresa, por isso optei para que a base ficasse localmente e  não em rede. Pretendo usar o MySQL ou SQLite. Tem como eu instalar a base de dados junto com a aplicação? Por exemplo: quando baixo qualquer programa da internet, parece que a base de dados é instalada junto com a aplicação. Estou usando o InnoSetup.

Comment: Se eu não me engano o InnoSetup dá a opção de 'anexar' o arquivo `sqlite` junto com o instalador

Comment: Você está misturando alguns conceitos. O termo certo não é compilar, mas instalar. Você forneceu poucos detalhes pra te ajudar. Mas se entendi bem, vá para o SQLite. Não escolha MySQL e SQL Server para rodar localmente. Em muitos casos é um tiro de canhão para matar uma borboleta. Um overhead desnecessário. SQLite não precisa ser instsalado. Você só precisa colocar no seu instalador o arquivo do banco + DLL. Não é a toa que no Android o SQLite seja tão utilizado. Simples e funcional.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78774/instalar-o-sqlserver-com-a-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o

Comment: Desculpe bigown. Sua resposta me ajudou. No decorrer do dia a dia esqueci de marcar. Acabei de marcar como resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O MySQL dá, em tese. O trabalho é monumental e complexo. Mas estou falando só por curiosidade, não é o que você quer.

O que se usa nestes casos é o [SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101). Você tem que baixar o *assembly* dele e mandar junto com a aplicação. Claro que a sua aplicação deve saber trabalhar com ele. Precisará entender como usar o *assembly* no seu projeto, como programar para ele, como adicionar na sua instalação, etc. Além de aprender como usá-lo obviamente.

Como você parece estar bem crú com isto vou te passar o básico e você vai perguntando conforme vai tendo dúvidas.

Você pode instalar um dos componentes nos *links* abaixo. Tem os arquivos necessários para a execução e auxiliadores de tempo de desenho do Visual Studio.

- [Página "oficial" do SQLite para o .NET](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).
- [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) (tem link para tudo na página acima).
- [Tutorial básico](https://web.archive.org/web/20201128115931/http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-using-sqlite-with-.net.aspx).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).