# Fiz o meu primeiro programa e agora preciso rodar ele no cliente. Como faço?

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

Fiz o meu primeiro programa e agora preciso rodar ele no cliente. Como faço?

Fiz meu banco com o SQL Server Express 2016. Meu windows é 64 bits. 
Pensei em instalar o mesmo banco no cliente, porém o sistema lá é 32 bits.

Há alguma forma de passar o arquivo do banco de dados junto com o meu programa? Sem precisar instalar o SQL Server?

Essa é minha string de conexão:

```
 private string StrCon = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MartinezSis1.0;Data Source=LATITUDENOTE\SQLEXPRESS";
```

Comment: A pergunta está confusa, mas talvez seja duplicata desta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80849/101

Comment: Que tecnologia você usou pra desenvolver?

Comment: Utilizei a linguagem c# .net

Comment: Na minha maquina esta rodando perfeitamente...Agora preciso levar isso para o cliente...Esse sistema vai ficar em uma maquina só...Banco de dados local mesmo..Bem parecido com o link que me passou

Comment: @GilbertoLiradaCruz Tudo bem, você usou C#. Mas é ASP.NET? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: É  WindowsForms.............

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Instalar banco de dados junto com a aplicação C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80849/instalar-banco-de-dados-junto-com-a-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-c)

Comment: @GilbertoLiradaCruz - Você necessita instalar o banco de dados completo (estrutura + dados) ou somente a estrutura do banco de dados?

Answer (score -1):

Gilberto, o banco de dados em si (isto é, os dados) independe de arquitetura (32 ou 64 bits). Mas você terá que primeiro instalar o SQL Server Express 2016 de 32 bits no computador do cliente.

No seu computador, você faz o backup completo (full) do banco de dados e então restaura esse backup no computador do cliente.

A seguir, altere a string de conexão, considerando-se as características do novo servidor.

- [Criar um backup completo de banco de dados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187510.aspx)
- [BACKUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186865.aspx)
- [Restaurar um banco de dados em um novo local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186390.aspx)